# non-metric multi-dimensional scaling in R: help with plotting and understanding Stress for isoMDS vs. metaMDS

Tags: r, multidimensional-scaling

I have a dataframe with 900 observations. There are 11 columns: 9 measured variables and 1 representing region.

```
 POINTID Region    X1       X2       X3      X4      X5     X6      X7      X8     X9     X10
 1         A       21.42    0.54    -0.20   23.91   0.67    4.54    0.72    33.77   0.12    5.99
 2         A       7.33     0.61    -0.23   6.21    0.56    3.96    0.73    10.00   0.69    6.62
 3         B       8.01     0.58    -0.29   7.31    0.43    4.40    0.53    10.69   0.69    3.93
 4         C       11.52    0.38    -0.22   2.49    0.96    3.92    0.64    1.40    0.76    6.96
```

...

I want to create a plot that shows how the observations fall out in multidimensional space, i.e., to show how separable the different regions are.

I've been advised that non-metric multi-dimensional scaling would be appropriate.

First, I have to create a distance matrix. So, I use the function dist() in R.

```
d <- dist(mydata)
```

Then I use this distance matrix in the isoMDS() function in the MASS library in R.

```
fit <- isoMDS(d,k=2,maxit=20,trace=TRUE)
```

Then I plot the data.

```
    plot(fit$points, type="n")
    #Label them with Region rather than POINTID
    text(fit$points, labels = mydata$Region, cex=.7)
```

Question1: How do I make a plot that shows the results of the MDS plotted with respect to the original 9 measured variables? I'd like to see along which variables in particular are they most separable.

Question2: When I use isoMDS() from the MASS library, I get a very high Stress value (0.2). 
I also tried using the metaMDS() function from the vegan library. In this case I get much lower stress values (approx 0.01). 
Can someone explain why this might be?

Comment: Regarding Q1, MDS does not generally result in a 2D representation that corresponds to the 9D in your data set. When you say "I'd like to see which variables are most separable (significant)", you are looking for Principle Component Analysis . See slide 27 in this for comparison: http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~iyad/PCA.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @ MrMeritology. I will do some more research.

Comment: Actually I think what may work best for me is to use canonical discriminant analysis in order to see how separable the groups are and what variable separates them most.